# How to prevent .load() from browser console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, web

I want some content of my website to be dynamically loaded after login. A `$.post(...)` interacts with a servlet which validates the user's credentials, and then a `$.load(url)` loads the content from a separate page into a `<div>`. I noticed that, as long as I know where to fetch the content from, I can force this behavior from the chrome javascript console, bypassing validation.

How can I prevent a user from doing this?

Comment: The validation/authentification should be handled server side

Comment: @A.Wolff validation is actually handled server side.

Comment: @pr0gma — It sounds like it is for `...` but not for `url`

Comment: On your server side code that will be hit by the $.load(url) you'll need to throw a 403 or no content at all if the user is not logged in. I assume you're using session cookies as your authentication method.

Comment: @pr0gma: If the user is authenticated and knows where to fetch the resource and that works then everything is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Once a document has been delivered to the user's browser it is completely under the control of the user. They can run any JS they like.

The URLs you present on your webserver are the public interface to it. Anyone can request them. You can use authentication/authorization to limit who gets a response, but you can't make that response conditional on the user running specific JavaScript that you supply.

The server needs to authorize the user **each time** it delivers restricted data. You can't do it once and then trust the browser to enforce it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a secret parameter to the url you load. By defining a random variable in the users `session` (server side) or in the database, and then return this variable once the validation is successful so your javascript code can use the variable in the next load call. In the load url you can check at the server side if the secret parameter had the correct value or not.

Hope its clear.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: **You Can't**.

JavaScript runs within the browser and therefore a user or application can run their own code whenever the feel like. This could be as simple as adding new CSS or running their own JS codes.

The main thing you can do to disable this is to ensure all of the requests are validated on your server side before being run as well as allowing only entry for certain types of information (like only allowing integers as numbers to stop strings coming through).

Something close to this sort of problem is XSS or Cross-Site Scripting. A 3rd party will try to inject some malicious code to a trusted website, usually some form of POST, to affect different users. Here is some more information on the matter

- [Cross-Site Scripting - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
- [CSS - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Comment: This has nothing to do with XSS. XSS is when a third party attacker injects JavaScript into your site which executes on your visitor's browser. It has nothing to do with a user running a script themselves.

Comment: I have always seen any form of JavaScript injection as XSS as its malicious to a trusted website. I will re-word that section then. In any case I would guess the OP doesn't want any injections onto his website.